# Not able to create Multiple slave on slave window box in Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I created a slave on windows machine(abc.ozc.local) from Linux jenkin and it is working fine.
Now I am trying to create another slave on same window machine and getting error(abc.ozc.local).This issue is when I am trying to make it as a service it is giving an error.As per my understanding the slave which is already running on the window box is having "Jenkin Slave" display name for service and it is trying to create the same display name for another service.I tried to edit the jenkins-config.xml file and changed the service name and display name but didn't work for me.When I start the service it make it Jenkin Slave as a display name

Could someone assist me how we can make 3-4 slave on slave window box.Jenkins master is on Linux

[image]

Comment: For the love of God, please don't post error messages as screenshots. There is not a snowflake's chance in hell that this would ever show up in a text search.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create multiple slave.The issue was it was not creating the display Name of the service unique.So I used the below command to change the Display name of the service and it worked

sc config servicename DisplayName= "Display name of the service"

Thanks